# Do I have copyright over the code I write in my Computer Science class

Tags: united-states, copyright, texas

Hypothetical Question: Do I have the right (copyright) over the code I write in my Computer Science class and thus all rights that come along with having something copyrighted?

I was wondering if I have copyright over the code that I write for my class as I am a paid programmer I would not like for any of my code to be stored on the instructor's "secure" server. And if they refused to do so, could I send a cease and desist to have it removed?

Edit: Yes I know this is a bit extreme, but I just want to know if I have copyright over it through intellectual property or some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing the code on your own, or are you following some kind of formula or instructions? In the first case, you should meet the originality requirement and be eligible for copyright protection.

Still, if *you* made the copy and put it on her server, I doubt that your copyright protection would give you much help. Copyright gives you the exclusive right to make copies; it doesn't give you the exclusive right to possess copies. Since she legally obtained the copy -- from you, no less -- there's nothing to tell her to cease and desist from.

On a more practical level, I suppose you could refuse to make copies and give them to her, but I think you should probably expect to fail the course.

Side note: You mentioned that you're a paid programmer, but I'm assuming that arrangement is separate from the class. If not, it would raise other issues that might change the answer here.

Comment: Might also be worth reading the student handbook or other documents you agreed to follow as part of attendance. Some colleges do actually require transferring copyright on some works to the university, or have language granting them full ans unlimited use of submitted works.